# when video not start launch a dialog to back main activity

Tags: android, android-videoview, rtsp

this is my code to videoview

```
try {

            // Start the MediaController
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    SingleItemView.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(video));
            videoview.requestFocus();
            videoview.setKeepScreenOn(true);

            videoview
                    .setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        // Close the progress bar and play the video
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            videoview.start();
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but the dialog is still remain if video stream is not working..

i want to put dialog to back to main activity if video is not working..

how can i do that?

i try put dialog but still not working i dont know why..

thanks in advance :)

EDIT : i also try like this but still not working

```
try {
                    // Start the MediaController
                    MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                            SingleTrackActivity.this);
                    mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
                    // Get the URL from String VideoURL
                    videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
                    videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(duration));
                    videoview.requestFocus();
                    videoview.setKeepScreenOn(true);

                    videoview
                            .setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                // Close the progress bar and play the video
                                public void onPrepared(
                                        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    videoview.start();
                                }
                            });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            SingleTrackActivity.this).create();

                    // Setting Dialog Title
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

                    // Setting Dialog Message
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Video Play Error :"
                            + e.toString());

                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    System.out.println("Video Play Error :" + e.toString());
                    finish();
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The media player work is done asynchronously from your code. If the media failed to setup, then the fail will occur after the code finished your method. At the same time, `onPreparedListener` wasn't called since the media did't enter in a `PREPARED` state.
So try to add an [`OnErrorListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html):

```
videoview.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener(){
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // inform the user something went wrong
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        return true;
    }
});
```

If this doesn't work check what callback you're getting for your media player / videoview.

Comment: yeah it work when the video not working and the dialog is turning off too..
but i want to back to main activity or activity before the videoview, how can i do that? :) thanks

Comment: Can you please re-phrase or provide more details? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. I suppose you want to return to previous activity if the video failed to start?

Comment: yes like that, when video not start, back to previous activity..
sorry my english is bad :(

Comment: If you have a reference to your parent Activity make sure you call `finish()` on it.